# Como fazer um gif seja executado apenas uma vez?

Tags: html, imagem

Tenho um GIF e quero que ele apenas seja executado uma vez, sem haver repetições. Há alguma forma de fazer isso? Como?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abra a imagem em um editor gráfico e remova a opção de loop infinito.

Agora, com Javascript você pode criar uma imagem estática em um `canvas`. E depois de um tempo (no caso, duração do .gif) a imagem animada será removida e no lugar dela o `canvas` será exibido:

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnbr/heg1v89a/2/)

```js
(function(){
  
  var $gif         = document.querySelector('.gif'),
      GIF_DURATION = 1050;

  function handleGif(){
    
    // Cria o canvas com o mesmo tamanho da imagem.
    var $canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    $canvas.setAttribute('width', $gif.width);
    $canvas.setAttribute('height', $gif.height);
    
    // Desenha a imagem no canvas
    var context = $canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage($gif, 0, 0);
    
    // Remove a imagem e insere o canvas
    document.body.removeChild($gif);
    document.body.appendChild($canvas);
  }
  
  var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
   handleGif();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, GIF_DURATION);
  
})();
```

```html
<img class='gif' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7bin.gif'/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Olha Daniel encontrei algo que possa te ajudar: https://github.com/krasimir/gifffer

Com ele você consegue fazer o gif "tocar" uma única vez.

Inclua o `gifffer.min.js` na página.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gifffer.min.js"></script>
```

Ao invés de atribuir valor no src da sua imagem, utilize o `data-gifffer`.

```
 <img data-gifffer="image.gif" />
```

E por último adiciona a chamada do `Grifffer();` aonde quiser. Por exemplo:

```
window.onload = function() {
    Gifffer();
}
```

Comment: Poxa que bacana, não conhecia o gifffer

Comment: @RBoschini fiz uma poc com ele agora, pois fiquei tão curioso, sempre quis fazer isso com gif e nunca consegui hehehe